# What was the entrance to the Chamber of Secrets before indoor plumbing was invented?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

[Hogwarts Castle was built ~1000AD](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Hogwarts_Castle) by Salazar Slytherin and the other three founders.  But indoor plumbing (i.e., running water through pipes) wasn't developed until - well, I'm not sure, but [apparently it wasn't until the 1800s](http://www.portapotty.net/plumbing/). Now, Pottermore confirms it: https://twitter.com/pottermore/status/1081242428105998336

So the secret entrance to the Chamber of Secrets clearly wasn't via some kind of [sink outlet, ornate or not](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vD4cXWrfE7o).

And I believe it unlikely to have been through the [medieval equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garderobe) because, though it certainly would have been an excellent disguise for it, I can't see Salarar Slytherin building it that way for reasons of dignity.

So, what was the original design, when was the Castle renovated with indoor plumbing, who built the current secret entrance during those renovations, and how was it kept secret from all the other occupants of the Castle at that time and also the other renovators?

Comment: *"..indoor plumbing (i.e., running water through pipes) wasn't developed until - well, I'm not sure"* The Romans used pipes to guide water from aqueducts to homes. Mind you, there were no taps, just pipe caps with small holes that dripped water continuously.